# Can I use same public key for ssh handshake and authentication?

Tags: ssh, rsa, public-key-encryption, public-key

I have an application that is distributed and installed in many machines. There is a central machine which can request other machine where the application installed and the other machines can request the central machine. So the each installation will act as a server as well as client. I want to secure the access using ssh public key cryptography.

For simplicity, let's say server A(manager - which is installed first) and server B have the application installed.

Let's say when server B installed, server A's public key will be available in server B.

Also assume server A will make the first request to server B. When doing so,  the server A will get server B's public key during the handshake(by verifying the fingerprint, the key will be saved in server A) and server A will send its public key to server B for authentication. As server B already has the server A's public key, authentication successful?.

When server B wants to request server A, the server A will send its public key during the handshake and it is verified against the server A's public key available in server B. For authentication, server B will send its public key which will be verified against the public key that server A got during the previous request handshake(from server A to server B).

One point to note is, there is no user involved. The application is accessible to all the users of the machine.

My query is, do we need separate keys for handshake and authentication or as I described single key is enough?

Also please let me know the above explained security model will have any issues particularly security related?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: for simplicity, can I use the same public key in both authorized_keys file and known_hosts file?

Comment: What are you trying to gain by doing this? The host key goes in a certain set of files on the server. The user key goes in a certain set of files on the client. There's no benefit to trying to use the same key for both purposes. Keys aren't expensive or time-consuming to create.

Comment: Hi Kenster,

Thanks for your comment. keys are not expensive to create but sharing it with other end is bit tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is called [Host-Based authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-9) as described in the RFC4252, section 9. But note that is poses several security threads and using proper (openssh) certificates makes much more sense these days (or Kerberos).

Comment: thanks Jakuje. I am considering using certificates(self signed) instead of public keys. So so both ends will generate certificates and share other side. Do you see any difference except processing?

Comment: They can't be self-signed. They need to be signed by some "certificate authority" (another key), which the validating side trust. Check the manual page for `ssh-keygen` describing the certificates or some [guide](https://blog.habets.se/2011/07/OpenSSH-certificates) on the internet.

Comment: However note, that you can create and be your own CA.